# SingleOrDefault asynchronous in .net application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to get an entity asynchronously. I know how to get collection asynchronously, but not a single object. Here is the code I have for getting a collection:

```
MoviesService.Container _proxy;
```

_proxy is initialized in the constructor.  Here is the other code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IQueryable<MoviesService.Title> query = _proxy.Titles;
            var titles = await GetTitlesAsych(query);
            DataServiceCollection<MoviesService.Title> collection = new DataServiceCollection<MoviesService.Title>();
            collection.Load(titles);
            this.DataContext = collection;
        }
private Task<IEnumerable<MoviesService.Title>> GetTitlesAsych(IQueryable<MoviesService.Title> query)
        {
           DataServiceQuery<MoviesService.Title> dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<MoviesService.Title>)(query);
           return Task.Factory.FromAsync<IEnumerable<MoviesService.Title>>(dsQuery.BeginExecute, dsQuery.EndExecute, null);
        }
```

I am confused how to change this so it can be used to get a single entity.

I'm using web api 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the result set as a collection asynchronously. The list will contain 0 or 1 items. Then, use `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault` synchronously.

Let me just say that you shouldn't be using async on the server by default. Use it when you need it.

Comment: this is on the client... but in my web api, my controller are all asych methods... I have checked the use asych methods when creating controller.

Comment: Of course you want to use async methods on the server, with a single-thread synchronization context. Kills all concurrency-related problems without sacrificing performance if your server just accesses the database a lot.

Comment: @zmbq there usually is no intra-request concurrency at all. Async actually has the potential to introduce it. Also, your async code runs exclusively only for an individual request. Any app would perform extremely badly if only one core would be used by design. It is not like that.

Comment: With async, you've only got reentrancy to worry about, not actual concurrency. There's no need to lock anything. As for performance, you can have one or two server *processes* per core, get the performance you want without paying the price of subtle multithreading bugs.

Comment: @zmbq I can only repeat: async has no concurrency per request but different requests do run concurrently. The same statement goes for sync ASP.NET code. No difference there.;  This is not the node.js model. Async IO does have concurrency in .NET.